# How to create ssh connection between two devices on the LAN

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, vmware

I'm trying to create ssh connection between devices on the same network, I have say Device A, B, C, and D. device A, B,and C are dell laptops having windows 10 install on them while device D is an iphone. I have a VMWare installed on both laptop devices and on device A and B i have linux OS centos 7 installed while on C i installed ubuntu 16.04, I installed ssh on both laptops and could verify that it's up and running, I can connect to the VMWare on device A by logging in from SSH client installed in window OS of device A but i can't access device B by logging in from ssh client installed on device A. and the same problem goes to all other devices i have only connect to the linux OS on VMWare from the same host and can't make remove connection, I try to ping the IP of my devices(the host IP not the VMware IP) but found a very weird problem, device A can ping both device B,C and D but device B,Cand D can't ping device A, also device B,C and D can both ping each other. I have made a lot of research but but no luck, Any help on while this problem keep persisting and how to solve it ,

I also to install both Linux cent os 7 and ubuntu 16.04 on the VMWare on device A which has a host of windows OS actually and on this two linux system i can set up ssh connection, so I think this problem is not with the setting or configuration of ssh but it's with my main device they can't communicate with each other and they are on the same Network (LAN) ant help on why this is happening, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope some of this helps:-
- It sounds like you may be using the wrong network options for your VMs.
- I am not to familiar with VMWare but am familiar with Virtual Box and have had similar issues.
- Have you made sure you are using a Bridged Network and not a NAT? A NAT can access the outside web but doesn't really accept incoming connections as it goes through the hosts connection. A Bridged Network circumvents the host OSs connection and communicates directly to your network card to fetch packets as if it was a true, separate machine.
 Check [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) for a better explanation (using Virtual Box) and [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html) for VMWare's say on the matter.

Comment: I'm really greatful for your effort, that exactly has been my problem, and the solution you provided has just fixed the problem, changing to Bridged Network just save my day, thanks so much